# Laravel: ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I keep getting `ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object` in a Job I am running.
I am running:

```
$appData = $this->getAppData()

if ($appData->pending_validation) {
 //
}

public function getAppData()
{
    $apiKey = env('APP_SETUP_KEY');
    $client = new Client(['x-api-key'=> $apiKey]);

    $response = $client->request(
        'GET',
        'https://apps.customendpoint.com/app',
        [
            'headers' => [
                'x-api-key' => $apiKey,
            ],
        ]);

    return $response->getBody()->getContents();
}
```

The error is occuring on `$appData->pending_validation` but when I go to log $appData, I get: 
`{"blocked":true,"pending_validation":true}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
public function getAppData()
{
    $apiKey = env('APP_SETUP_KEY');
    $client = new Client(['x-api-key'=> $apiKey]);

    $response = $client->request(
        'GET',
        'https://apps.customendpoint.com/app',
        [
            'headers' => [
                'x-api-key' => $apiKey,
            ],
        ]);

    return json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
}
```

Otherwise, you can access by `$appData['pending_validation']`.

hopefully, it will be work.